# Is it possible to traverse nested SASS selectors to the parent selector?

Tags: css, sass

Just a question about the nesting of SASS selectors, so Im inside a nested span that I want to apply the `:hover` pseudo to so the opacity changes to 0, I also want to use this style though when the parent a tag gets the class `is-active`. Right now I would move the `is-active` class outside of the span and reapply the style but I'm wondering can you move up a level from within the nested style like traversing?

**My example SASS:**

```
.btn-lang {
    // styles...

    > span {
        // styles...

        &:hover { // i want to use this when btn-lang  has class is-active
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    // right now I would add these styles here but seems there could be an easier method?
    &.is-active {
        > span {
            &:hover {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reuse two selectors (`.btn-lang` and `span`) in a single construction. This is not possible with SASS.

This situation is where extends really shine:

```css
// Declaring a reusable extend that will not appear in CSS by itself.
%span-with-hover-on-active-element {
    & > span {
        /* styles for span under btn-lang */ }
    &.is-active > span:hover {
        opacity: 0; } }

.btn-lang {
    /* styles for btn-lang */
    // Apply the span-on-hover thing.
    @extend %span-with-hover-on-active-element; }
```

It makes complicated code reuable and easier to read.

Resulting CSS:

```css
.btn-lang > span {
  /* styles for span under btn-lang */
}
.is-active.btn-lang > span:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-lang {
  /* styles for btn-lang */
}
```

Comment: How does this save anything?  Unless the extend class is reused elsewhere (the OP never implies that they intend on doing so), this is just a convoluted way of doing what the OP wants.